# Stack Overflow vs Code Review vs Programming Puzzles & Code Golf vs Software Engineering

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I have read quite a bit about recommendations regarding choosing a proper
target site in the Stack Exchange universe (Stack Overflow, Code Review, Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, Software Engineering).

As rules of thumb:

- If I think my code has *bugs*, Stack Overflow is the proper place.
- If I think my code works, and I have more general questions (regarding design, style, etc) Code Review is the proper place.

Makes sense to me! **However**, [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog) on SE doesn't come close to, say, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) regarding the size of the community. While the Prolog community on Stack Overflow is alive and kicking, I have *barely seen any activity* regarding Prolog *on Code Review*.

The way I see things I basically have two choices:

1. Follow above rule of thumb and put code on Code Review to let it slumber there.
2. Break above rule of thumb and knowingly put inadequate content on Stack Overflow.

What are your thoughts, ideas, and recommendation on that issue?

---

P.S. For exactly the same reason I did not post this question to http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: I find it highly ironic that you decided to ask this question on Stack Overflow; considering your question has nothing to do with [a specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), Stack Overflow is definitely the **wrong** place to ask such a question.

Comment: @ChristianVarga: I believe this is the one exception where this sort of questions should be allowed here and not on meta: it's possible that prolog programmers don't go to meta often enough for this question to get answered here. This question cannot be answered by non-prolog programmers because they will never email/phone/knock-on-door of a prolog programmer when they see a prolog question. This question specifically is asking how the prolog community on SE behaves.

Comment: @repeat: I come from the good old "early" days when almost any question would be welcome here. While some of the effect of the Great Cleanup is indeed good I also notice that some other aspects of it is bad. It is especially bad for very niche issues (language/library/database etc) where it is actually harder now to get answers than it used to be.

Comment: @slebetman "it's possible that prolog programmers don't go to meta often enough for this question to get answered here". It's also possible that you're completely wrong. Of the [top prolog users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/topusers), false is a meta.SO regular, and the other top users seem to at least visit infrequently according to their profiles. But even if that were not the case, _this question is still off topic for SO_ and thus _should not be on SO_; saying "I think the people I want to ask are not on meta" is no excuse to post an off topic question to the main site.

Comment: Most non-trivial questions slumber even on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Boris the only thing I claim is that _this question belongs on meta.SO_ and thus it should be migrated there. I have no idea why you think that I'm making an argument about closure vs. votes.

Comment: @l4mpi I understand; the point I tried and failed to make is that migrating will _decrease exposure_, thus defeating the purpose.

Comment: @Boris As I argued in my first comment, that's wrong. The #2 prolog answerer and #1 asker is a meta.SO regular and _will_ see the question there; or at least would see it with a better title. Also, many more people who don't neccessarily have domain-specific prolog knowledge but do have a lot of SO/SE experience can weigh in on this. That's a huge audience which would currently be completely excluded. And lastly, you could say the same for any other off topic question - migrating something from SO to anywhere else always decreases exposure. That's still no reason to keep it on SO.

Comment: Using this logic, I should have never gone to Code Review, as I am essentially the only Objective-C/Swift reviewer. Someone at Code Review always has to be the first CRitter for any particular language. And CRitters actually tend to take an interest in lots of topics. Perhaps help us out and post a self-answered question to try jump starting the community for your language of choice?

Answer (score 14):

This is a three-stage question/process.

1. you have to decide whether the question is on-topic on Stack Overflow (regardless of the language tag and community)
2. you have to decide whether it is on-topic on another community
3. you have to have people on that other community willing and able to answer those questions.

In this particular case, your prolog questions are requests for code review. There is no specific problem in the code, and, as a result, it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. This is the exact reason why Code Review was 'created', to handle these types of questions which do not fit well with the Stack Overflow scope.

Then, it is clear that Code Review is the "right" place for questions like your reviews. We would love to have them.

The real question is whether we have a strong enough Prolog community to answer such questions. As you said, your question from a month ago has gone unanswered there. So, why is that? I suggest it's because the prolog community has been ***too*** nice, and ***too*** accomodating here on Stack Overflow. Instead of answering code review questions on Code Review, they are answering them here on Stack Overflow.

I would love for the community to expand on Code Review. There are benefits for everyone:

1. people with review questions are less confused about where to ask
2. people get the answers they want with less fear about being closed as off-topic
3. answerers get rewarded more in terms of reputation (Code Review has a somewhat different mind-set when it comes to voting).

Code Review answers are hard to make short (in either time, or words), and as a result they require some investment from the answerer. The answers are also normally not presented in a way that makes them generally useful as targets of search engines, etc. Good Code Review answers are never good answers for Stack Overflow (for a close approximation of "never" anyway).

So, I encourage your prolog community to at least "follow" [the prolog tag on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prolog?sort=newest). There are just 16 questions, I know, and the volume is small... but, with a few interested people, the community will become useful, and thriving. By following the tag, you get an e-mail "soon" after a prolog question is asked. If it interests you, great. I have seen it happen with other tags (VBA anyone?).

The ideal solution would be to have questions asked in the right places. To get this right, there needs to be awareness, and support. That can only happen when people do the right thing (ask and answer questions in the sites where they are on topic).

Comment: VBA tag now has a silver badger on CR. When we started working on making the tag badgeable, there were between 2 and 5 users posting answers. It just takes a will.

Comment: @false - I am not disputing your experience (and in fact, I agree that CR is not an extension to SO - which is exactly the point of my answer). In respect to your comment here though, just because you are not willing, comfortable, or able to participate in another site, does not make a code-review question on-topic here on SO.

Comment: @false - I don't follow you - a miscommunication somewhere? Anyone wanting to chat about this answer - feel free to find me in [the Code Review chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). Very happy to discuss there.